# Centos Web Panel not secure solution

Tags: linux, centos, web

Good day.

I am new to web development and is still trying to learn a lot of things.  Basically, I tried making my own linux web server**(Centos)** provided with a static ip I purchased. After the installation, I installed **Centos Web Panel** to my server. I then proceeded to my hosting which is `ipaddress:2030`.

After a few days, my address is now posting

```
Privacy error

Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from ipaddress (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

Accessing the site from edge and firefox usually prompts me to not proceed but I wanted it to be accessed normally just like the first time I installed it. What is causing this to happen? What can I do to stop this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's probably because you are using a self-signed certificate for SSL per the HTTPS  protocol. I'm guessing you did not pay for a trusted third party SSL certificate or set one up with Let's Encrypt and you are using a self-signed certificate. You can set your settings to trust the self-signed certificate on the client systems you access this system, purchase and deploy a third party CA certificate for this host of this domain, or setup accordingly with Let's Encrypt and/or certbot for example. I also believe a mismatch of the host name and the certificate may cause this error as well.

Comment: `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` essentially means your browser does not trust the HTTPS certificate in use (or rather, whomever it was supposedly issued by). You may want to edit your question to include information on the certificate(s) you are using on your server, as well as the exact circumstances under which you get this error i.e. what application(s) are generating this issue (any server side software).

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT How do I assign SSL to my hosting? Is it mandatory to buy one? Sorry for the newbie question

Comment: Here's a simple basic instruction http://wiki.centos-webpanel.com/hostname-ssl-with-letsencrypt but you could always backup the system and then research via Google, etc. search "Hostname SSL with Letsencrypt on CWP" and see if you can get it going.

Comment: If you set up with Let's Encrypt, it is free but the certs are only good and need to be renewed every 90 days. I use WHM and not CWP but you should be able to set it to auto renew. You will need to setup some records in your external DNS management system too.

Comment: @Anaksunaman I don't know what certificates are included. I just did the tutorial on how to install Centos and Centos Web Panel then proceeded with the creation of my website using the domain name I purchased at namecheap.

Comment: Marvin - Last comment but do some homework but this may be another resource to use too http://wiki.centos-webpanel.com/letsencrypt-free-ssl-on-cwp but remember I'm not familiar with CWP so look it up and backup your system before changing things just in case and keep track of whatever changes you make too in case you need to undo you have it documented what you changed. I'm not sure what's the latest version of CWP and the Let's Encrypt solution but I use Let's Encrypt for *.domain.com in my case you all my servers and it's not 100% automated yet.

Comment: Pimp Juice IT has you on the right path, then. Self-signed certificates (those that the system would have created itself) aren't typically trusted by browsers unless you explicitly allow them on a per site, per browser basis.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to resolve the issue:

+============+

1. Login the CWP panel using the IP address: `http://$IP_Address:2030`
2. Go to `Server Settings` on the left menu
3. Click on `Change Hostname`
4. Please ensure the hostname you're changing it to resolves to an IP address, and a PTR record resolving to your server host-name exists
5. After that enter the new hostname and click `Change Hostname`
6. SSL will be installed automatically, and you have to restart 03 services from the server: Dovecot, Postfix and CWPSrv

To restart the services, run below commands:

```
$ service dovecot restart
$ service postfix restart
$ service cwpsrv restart
```

Now run the CWP panel with your hostname.

Comment: I re-formatted your answer a bit. Please verify that I didn't change your meaning. [From Review](https://superuser.com/review/late-answers/1082947)